# Why do I get the letter 'h' followed by server's response

Tags: java, apache, tomcat8, spring-websocket, sockjs

I have recently put HTTPD in front of Tomcat as research said it was the best practice. However, sometimes when I go to pages that use websockets I get the letter 'h' followed by the server's response and sometimes just the h's. This includes JSON responses as well.

This is the latest message I received:

```
h
h
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>502 Bad Gateway</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Gateway</h1>
<p>The proxy server received an invalid
response from an upstream server.<br />
</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at www.domain.com Port 443</address>
</body></html>
```

Please note in this case the response happened to be an error from the server but sometimes I get the actual raw HTML that I am expecting but cannot display correct because of the preceding h's. The number of h's can be higher than two or even just one. For the JSON response I get

```
h
{json object}
```

I have increased the timeout on the worker as suggested by other tutorials but without success.

Comment: Do you have mod_substitute or mod_ext_filter configured?

Comment: @covener No I don't have them configured